# Kendo ui sortable trigger start-event when click on spezific area

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, dojo, kendo-sortable

i would like customize my kendo Sortable function. I want to start drag my row when i click on the last cell of the row.

I think it would be the easiest, when i trigger the event "start", but i cant trigger the event by myself.

Here is my work at the moment: [My Work](https://dojo.telerik.com/eRiwu).

My question is how can i sort a row by just click the last cell?

(Its my first question so if you can give me some tipps to improve my question skills, pls let me know) :)

best wishes lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to bind a custom click event for that, just define [`handler`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable#configuration-handler) property:

```
$("#sortable").kendoSortable({
  filter: "tr",
  handler: "td.StartDrag",
  hint: function(element) {
    return $("<span></span>")
      .text(element.text())
      .css("color", "#FF0000");
  },
  start: function(e){
            //the event i wanna trigger with clicking on the last cell
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eRiwu/2)

Comment: Thank you, just looked on the events for this one >.<

Comment: One extra question: 
when i set the list on sortable the mouse events cant be used anymore (e. g. marking the text).
Can i set this issue only to my last cell, too?

Comment: @LukasSedelmaier I'm afraid I can't help you with that. Checked it here, and it seems to be an expected behaviour. You could post this issue on kendo's forums so any dev could help you with that. I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi, 
btw kendo integrated this in the sortable event. Just look for "ignore".